# Loopback - Custom Api not getting displayed in explorer

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have created a remote method in my model named "FreeEmailProviders" that contains fields "id" and "domainname".

The code for creating the remote method is as follows:

```
    FreeEmailProviders.checkEmailDomain = function(email, cb) {
        cb(null, email);  
    };

    FreeEmailProviders.remoteMethod(
        'checkEmailDomain',
        {
            http: {path: '/checkEmailDomain', verb: 'get'},
            accepts: {arg: 'email', type: 'string'},
            returns: {arg: 'isEmailFreeProvider', type: 'string'}
        }
    );
```

Now when i am running the application, this method is not displaying in the list of APIs for this method.

When i am running the api directly in the browser, that is when i am calling the url:
http://localhost:4000/api/FreeEmailProviders/checkEmailDomain?email=test@gmail.com

I am getting the below error:

```
{"error":{"name":"Error","status":404,"message":"Unknown \"FreeEmailProviders\" id \"checkEmailDomain\".","statusCode":404,"code":"MODEL_NOT_FOUND","stack":"Error: Unknown \"FreeEmailProviders\" id \"checkEmailDomain\".\n    at Function.convertNullToNotFoundError }}
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Can you verify that this model is within the /sever/model-config.json file?

Comment: @JSimonsen : Yes its defined over there. If it wont be defined i wont be able to see the inbuilt methods that the model provides.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. After 3 hours I figured I had a typo in the *.js file.

If you used the model generator you should not run into this issue. If you created the files yourself make sure the .json and .js file in common/models have exact the same name except for the extension.

It would be nice if Loopback throws an error in such cases.